# enum and closure combination

Tags: swift, enums, closures

```
    private enum Operation {
        case BinaryOperation((Double, Double) -> Double)
        case UrinaryOperation((Double) -> Double)
    }
    let plus = Operation.BinaryOperation({$0 + $1})
    let minus = Operation.BinaryOperation({$0 - $1})
    let multiply = Operation.BinaryOperation({$0 * $1})
    let divide = Operation.BinaryOperation({$0 / $1})


    plus(3.0,2.0)
```

However, I got the following error:

MyPlayground.playground:5:13: error: cannot call value of non-function type 'Operation'
        plus(3.0,2.0)
        ~~~~^

Comment: The word is "unary", not "urinari"...

Comment: The definition is correct, however, the enum case won't become magically a function. You need to access the associated value (which is a closure) and then call that closure.

Comment: Cheers, forgive my poor English

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct syntax for what you are trying to do is:

```
if case let Operation.BinaryOperation(operation) = plus {
    operation(3.0, 2.0) // results in 5.0
}
```

You need to get the associated value of the enum.

---

Note that your closures can be simplified to

```
let plus = Operation.BinaryOperation(+)
let minus = Operation.BinaryOperation(-)
let multiply = Operation.BinaryOperation(*)
let divide = Operation.BinaryOperation(/)
```

Comment: @leonshi If this solves your issue, please click on the checkmark to the left of the answer. That let's people know your question has been solved.